# Azure CDN with SAS token caching mechanism

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, pre-signed-url, azure-cdn

I have a blob container with restricted public access. Azure CDN is set up on top of it. Please find the  below example

Cache Duration: 24 hours

Azure Storage URL: http://azstorage5.blob.core.windows.net/images/img15.jpg

CDN Endpoint: http://az507925.vo.msecnd.net/

Azure Storage SAS parameter: ?st=2020-12-07T19%3A21%3A09Z&se=2020-12-08T20%3A21%3A09Z&sr=c&sp=r&sig=STTE1p0ujzZr31ZjPaOlNoImCPcjss2GoRsOWDlpJuI%3D

Final CDN URL: http://az507925.vo.msecnd.net/images/img1.jpg?st=2020-12-07T19%3A21%3A09Z&se=2020-12-08T20%3A21%3A09Z&sr=c&sp=r&sig=STTE1p0ujzZr31ZjPaOlNoImCPcjss2GoRsOWDlpJuI%3D

If I set cache behavior as [Ignore query strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAQAO.png) in the CDN

**Question:** For the first time when tried to access the image img15.jpg, it will be retrieved from blob container and is cached in CDN. If I access the img15.jpg multiple times with different valid SAS tokens within the cache expiration(24 hours) period, will it be served from cache or will it fetch from blob container for every unique valid SAS token?

**End Goal:** I want the image to be cached on the CDN and should be able to access it with valid SAS tokens but without hitting the blob container as long as the cache is not expired. Is this a possible use case scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, if using different valid SAS token for a same blob(like blob1), the blob1 with different SAS token will be directly fetched from blob container for the first time of access.

For example, access by using blob1?sastoken1 first, then access by using blob1?sastoken2, at this time, the blob1?sastoken2 will be fetched directly from blob container.

I suggest you can use the same sastoken, or you can define a [stored access policy](https://husseinsalman.com/securing-access-to-azure-storage-part-5-stored-access-policy/) to visit the blob.

Comment: Ignore query strings: In this mode, the CDN point-of-presence (POP) node passes the query strings from the requestor to the origin server on the first request and caches the asset. All subsequent requests for the asset that are served from the POP ignore the query strings until the cached asset expires.

Bypass caching for query strings: In this mode, requests with query strings are not cached at the CDN POP node. The POP node retrieves the asset directly from the origin server and passes it to the requestor with each request.

Comment: Even in the Ignore query strings mode do you think a different SAS token will fetch the resource from the blob container even though the resource cache is not expired on CDN?

Comment: @krisjans, yes, even with `ignore query strings` mode, a different SAS token will fetch the resource from the blob container. you can do a test with that mode and open fiddler to see the response(or from browser, press F12 button), if the response contains `x-cache: hit`, it means it fetches content from CDN.

Comment: Here is the test from my side: when using blob1?sas_token_1 in browser, the first time(after press F12 button), the response is 200 status code; then you can refresh the page, the response is 304, and there is a `x-cache:hit` in the response. when you using another sastoken, like blob1?sas_token_2 to visit it, the first you can see 200 status code, and no `x-cache:hit` in the response.

Comment: @krisjans did you get solution to for this ? I required solution for same situation where I need CDN and also SAS that expire in 1 hour so after 1 hour, it required new SAS but that time it should fetch from CDN POP not from origin.

Comment: @IvanYang as you mentioned it will fetch from CDN POP from next time but thing is if we don't pass SAS it will still fetch data as we have mentioned to ignore query string so there is no meaning of SAS. so is there a way to achieve both SAS an CDN with unique query string ?

Answer (score 0):

if you configure CDN to cache every sas string, this is expected that files won't be cached, because for CDN they are different files.

if you configure to ignore the sas string, this will end up with unauthenticated users getting access to cached files (just omit parameters, or paste garbage there).

The solution here is to properly construct sas string.

You can give the same parameters for the file do all the clients today:
access start time 00:00 today,
end time the end of next day.

This will let all the clients requesting file today to have cached copy, and one day ahead to complete download.